# Is it okay to register defaults to NSUserDefaults from multiple classes in my app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsuserdefaults, preferences

I have read and understand the way `NSUserDefaults` can be used to save preferences for my app to the file system. I am also aware of the need to register defaults before using them later in the app.

What I am not sure of, however, is if it is okay to register defaults from various classes in my app. For example, in the `AppDelegate` I want to register a preference that belongs to the entire app, but in a Theme-class I want to use (and therefore register) preferences only used for getting and setting the app's theme. More classes will have their own needs as far as user defaults go, so this applies to multiple parts of any project I work on.

Is this way of keeping the preferences with the classes they belong to the correct way of working?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can register defaults from multiple classes. When you register a new default, it just adds that new key/value pair to the registration domain (there is only one of those for the app). I think the way you're doing it is quite reasonable.

Comment: Thank you for actually answering my real question, which was about **registering** defaults from many parts in my app, not just setting and getting them (I totally understood that was possible).
Now I can **register** defaults a certain class needs in the init of this class without caring about what other classes might do in my app, and that is how it should be in Object Oriented Programming, right?

Comment: That is my understanding, and in testing it, it seemed to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

The NSUserDefaults are related to the entire application. So, it's not important where you read/store them: the keys will be visible to any class even when they're set in another.

I personally try to use my own schemes, so related preferences could be "close".

i.e:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:themePreferences forKey:@"Theme"];
[defaults setObject:otherPreferences forKey:@"Other"];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I understand that the user defaults can be read and written from the entire app, but my real question is whether I can **register** them as well from multiple places in my app, or do I have to pass the complete dictionary of defaults in one call to registerDefaults?

Comment: are you concerned of memory while you hold the user defaults, or you want to call the defaults on one line? If your concern is neither, state it so we can help.

Comment: You could do both. Try to think of it as a shared Dictionary, so you can set all the preferences at once, or just set/read part of it. Of course, if you plan to write them all in a single call, you should be aware that you may lose previous data written by another class in your code.

Comment: Memory was not my concern, and I do not want to register them all from one line, on the contrary, I want to register a default in the class that needs it, so in multiple places in my app. @rdelmar cleared this up for me, I will code it today and if anything bad still happens I will be back here with more details...

Answer (score 1):

This isn't necessary, but if you wanted to zone your preferences file by class, you could include the class name as part of the key. For example:

```
NSString *prefKey = [ NSString stringWithFormat: @"%s.prefName", (const char *) class_getName([ self class ]) ];
```

Where `prefName` is the name of whatever preference you're storing. That way you could use the same preference name with different classes, and not worry about them overwriting one another. But as others have said, unless you have a specific need to do this, `NSUserDefaults` can be called from anywhere in the application.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` that will be shared within entire application. And you can use your own defaults classes for class-specific settings.